# What game is this character in the Pixels movie from?

Tags: game-identification

What is this arcade character from? (this is from the Pixels movie)

[image: https://laughingsquid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/tumblr_nnkvblJbs91tuxqamo1_1280.jpg]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is one of the red-winged moth-looking enemies from Galaga.

[image: Screenshot of Galaga]
<sup>Screenshot from [mediamatic.net](https://www.mediamatic.net/en/page/61201/galaga-screenshot)</sup>

Somewhat fittingly, the logo for Arqade, the spaceship, is also from Galaga.

Comment: The ship in the Arqade.SE is inspired by Galaga. I am pretty sure the ship's design for the game is copyrighted. Unless you have a source that the stack indeed used it. [citation needed]

Comment: @Mindwin The original ship was less stylized, but it definitely was inspired by it.

Comment: Hey, move the ship to the left.  You want it captured by that blue shield!